# Valgrind — heap stats are weird: memory leak?

Tags: c, macos, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind is giving me crazy high number for the number of frees, allocs and bytes allocated as well as not realising that I have freed memory in heap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    return 0;
}

gcc -std=c99 -g -Werror -Wextra -pedantic valgrind.c
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
==44611== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==44611== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==44611== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==44611== Command: ./a.out
==44611== 
==44611== 
==44611== HEAP SUMMARY:
==44611==     in use at exit: 22,223 bytes in 183 blocks
==44611==   total heap usage: 259 allocs, 76 frees, 28,335 bytes allocated
==44611== 
==44611== LEAK SUMMARY:
==44611==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44611==         suppressed: 22,223 bytes in 183 blocks
==44611== 
==44611== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==44611== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 16 from 16)
```

It's telling me I have `259 allocs, 76 frees, 28,335 bytes allocated` which is crazy high when I have literally nothing in my program. I'm getting scared that my previous days of never freeing malloced space has created memory leaks. If so, any idea how I can reclaim previous malloced memory on my Mac? I am using El Capitan.

Comment: You `return` before the `free`. The compiler should have told you that the `free` is unreachable.

Comment: thanks for solving that part of the question

Comment: Welcome to Mac OS X.  Use `--leak-check=full` (probably with `--num-callers=100`) to check that the leaks are out of your control, and then use  `--gen-suppressions=all` to generate suppressions into a file, and then rerun with `--suppressions=suppresions-file` to see that they've all gone.  There's a lot of memory allocation done by the OSX startup code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Will this free all allocated memory? do i type this in valgrind?

Comment: The figures you are seeing are static objects used by the C library implementation, don't worry about them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, this is semi-normal for Mac OS X, at least until you've tuned the system.  I had to add quite a lot of suppressions (generated by Valgrind) for El Capitan.

The first thing to note is that your code allocates no memory, so there is no way your code can leak any memory.  Anything that is leaked, or potentially leaked, is done by the OS before your program gets started.

The next thing to note is that there isn't much either to worry about or that you can do about it even if you do decide to worry about it.  Your best bet, by far, is to let Valgrind know that you know about this and get on with life.

So, how do you tell Valgrind?

Stage 1 is running Valgrind with `--leak-check=full` and `--num-callers=100`.  For example, running on my El Capitan with your program as `leaks.c`, I got:

```
==43058== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==43058== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==43058== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==43058== Command: leaks
==43058== 
--43058-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--43058-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97!
--43058-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 2 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 4 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 8 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 16 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 32 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3406, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43058-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 8 times)
--43058-- UNKNOWN host message [id 412, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43058-- UNKNOWN host message [id 222, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43058-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3410, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
==43058== 
==43058== HEAP SUMMARY:
==43058==     in use at exit: 22,245 bytes in 187 blocks
==43058==   total heap usage: 263 allocs, 76 frees, 28,341 bytes allocated
==43058== 
==43058== LEAK SUMMARY:
==43058==    definitely lost: 4,416 bytes in 4 blocks
==43058==    indirectly lost: 2,288 bytes in 6 blocks
==43058==      possibly lost: 7,096 bytes in 68 blocks
==43058==    still reachable: 8,445 bytes in 109 blocks
==43058==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43058== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==43058== 
==43058== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==43058== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I don't like those `UNKNOWN` messages, but that may mean I need to rebuild.  Note that I got the code from SVN — see the version number.

Now, running again:

```
$ valgrind --num-callers=100 --leak-check=full ./leaks

==43059== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==43059== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==43059== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==43059== Command: ./leaks
==43059== 
--43059-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--43059-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97!
--43059-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 2 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 4 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 8 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 16 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 32 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3406, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43059-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 8 times)
--43059-- UNKNOWN host message [id 412, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43059-- UNKNOWN host message [id 222, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43059-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3410, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
==43059== 
==43059== HEAP SUMMARY:
==43059==     in use at exit: 22,245 bytes in 187 blocks
==43059==   total heap usage: 263 allocs, 76 frees, 28,341 bytes allocated
==43059== 
==43059== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 9 of 62
==43059==    at 0x100006355: malloc_zone_calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==43059==    by 0x1004FE4B1: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FE1BE: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FE053: NXCreateHashTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FD037: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FBB4D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FB538: map_2_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC047CF: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC04516: dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x10016689D: dyld_register_image_state_change_handler (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FB07A: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x10010EC4B: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x10010EC37: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x100010A01: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC12F1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC13093: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F6CC: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F661: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F552: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F7C2: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC020AA: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC05D46: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC01275: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC01035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059== 
==43059== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 10 of 62
==43059==    at 0x100006355: malloc_zone_calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==43059==    by 0x1004FE4B1: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x100500223: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FD90C: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FBB4D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FB538: map_2_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC047CF: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC04516: dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x10016689D: dyld_register_image_state_change_handler (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x1004FB07A: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x10010EC4B: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x10010EC37: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x100010A01: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC12F1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC13093: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F6CC: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F661: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F552: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F7C2: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC020AA: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC05D46: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC01275: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC01035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059== 

…lots of text missing…

==43059== 
==43059== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 62 of 62
==43059==    at 0x100007110: malloc_zone_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:769)
==43059==    by 0x100504D71: (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::autoreleaseNoPage(objc_object*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x100504CF5: objc_autoreleasePoolPush (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x100504998: call_load_methods (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x100501B9D: load_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC01DE0: dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F6B9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F552: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F580: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F7C2: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC020AA: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC05D46: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC01275: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059==    by 0x7FFF5FC01035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43059== 
==43059== LEAK SUMMARY:
==43059==    definitely lost: 4,416 bytes in 4 blocks
==43059==    indirectly lost: 2,288 bytes in 6 blocks
==43059==      possibly lost: 7,096 bytes in 68 blocks
==43059==    still reachable: 8,445 bytes in 109 blocks
==43059==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43059== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==43059== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==43059== 
==43059== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==43059== ERROR SUMMARY: 17 errors from 17 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

When you look at those stack traces, you can see that there is no entry for `main` in them.  That indicates that the problem is not in your code; it is in the system code.  So, you rerun Valgrind again with `--gen-suppressions=all`, and get output like:

```
$ valgrind --gen-suppressions=all --num-callers=100 --leak-check=full ./leaks
==43060== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==43060== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==43060== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==43060== Command: ./leaks
==43060== 
--43060-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--43060-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97!
--43060-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 2 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 4 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 8 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 16 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 32 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3406, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43060-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 8 times)
--43060-- UNKNOWN host message [id 412, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43060-- UNKNOWN host message [id 222, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43060-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3410, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
==43060== 
==43060== HEAP SUMMARY:
==43060==     in use at exit: 22,245 bytes in 187 blocks
==43060==   total heap usage: 263 allocs, 76 frees, 28,341 bytes allocated
==43060== 
==43060== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 9 of 62
==43060==    at 0x100006355: malloc_zone_calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==43060==    by 0x1004FE4B1: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FE1BE: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FE053: NXCreateHashTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FD037: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FBB4D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FB538: map_2_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC047CF: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC04516: dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x10016689D: dyld_register_image_state_change_handler (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FB07A: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x10010EC4B: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x10010EC37: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x100010A01: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC12F1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC13093: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F6CC: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F661: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F552: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F7C2: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC020AA: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC05D46: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC01275: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC01035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: possible
   fun:malloc_zone_calloc
   fun:NXHashInsert
   fun:NXCreateHashTableFromZone
   fun:NXCreateHashTable
   fun:_read_images
   fun:map_images_nolock
   fun:map_2_images
   fun:_ZN4dyldL18notifyBatchPartialE17dyld_image_statesbPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:_ZN4dyld36registerImageStateBatchChangeHandlerE17dyld_image_statesPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
   fun:dyld_register_image_state_change_handler
   fun:_objc_init
   fun:_os_object_init
   fun:libdispatch_init
   fun:libSystem_initializer
   fun:_ZN16ImageLoaderMachO18doModInitFunctionsERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextE
   fun:_ZN16ImageLoaderMachO16doInitializationERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader19processInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader15runInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextERNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   fun:_ZN4dyld24initializeMainExecutableEv
   fun:_ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_Pm
   fun:_ZN13dyldbootstrap5startEPK12macho_headeriPPKclS2_Pm
   fun:_dyld_start
}
==43060== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 10 of 62
==43060==    at 0x100006355: malloc_zone_calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==43060==    by 0x1004FE4B1: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x100500223: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FD90C: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FBB4D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FB538: map_2_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC047CF: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC04516: dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x10016689D: dyld_register_image_state_change_handler (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x1004FB07A: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x10010EC4B: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x10010EC37: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x100010A01: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC12F1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC13093: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F6CC: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F661: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F552: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F7C2: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC020AA: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC05D46: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC01275: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC01035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060== 

…lots of material omitted again…

==43060== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 62 of 62
==43060==    at 0x100007110: malloc_zone_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:769)
==43060==    by 0x100504D71: (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::autoreleaseNoPage(objc_object*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x100504CF5: objc_autoreleasePoolPush (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x100504998: call_load_methods (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x100501B9D: load_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC01DE0: dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F6B9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F552: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F580: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC0F7C2: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC020AA: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC05D46: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC01275: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060==    by 0x7FFF5FC01035: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==43060== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc_zone_memalign
   fun:_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage17autoreleaseNoPageEP11objc_object
   fun:objc_autoreleasePoolPush
   fun:call_load_methods
   fun:load_images
   fun:_ZN4dyldL12notifySingleE17dyld_image_statesPK11ImageLoader
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader19processInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader19processInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader15runInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextERNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   fun:_ZN4dyld24initializeMainExecutableEv
   fun:_ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_Pm
   fun:_ZN13dyldbootstrap5startEPK12macho_headeriPPKclS2_Pm
   fun:_dyld_start
}
==43060== LEAK SUMMARY:
==43060==    definitely lost: 4,416 bytes in 4 blocks
==43060==    indirectly lost: 2,288 bytes in 6 blocks
==43060==      possibly lost: 7,096 bytes in 68 blocks
==43060==    still reachable: 8,445 bytes in 109 blocks
==43060==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43060== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==43060== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==43060== 
==43060== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==43060== ERROR SUMMARY: 17 errors from 17 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

And you collect the suppressions into a file, replacing the `<insert_a_suppression_name_here>` with something more useful.  For example, I previously created an entry:

```
{
   Mac-OS-X-El-Capitan-System-Leak.019
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc_zone_memalign
   fun:_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage17autoreleaseNoPageEP11objc_object
   fun:objc_autoreleasePoolPush
   fun:call_load_methods
   fun:load_images
   fun:_ZN4dyldL12notifySingleE17dyld_image_statesPK11ImageLoader
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader19processInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader19processInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListERNS_15UninitedUpwardsE
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader15runInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextERNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   fun:_ZN4dyld24initializeMainExecutableEv
   fun:_ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_Pm
}
```

That was saved in a file `suppressions`.  If I run the code with my previous suppressions file (which I happen to have in the same directory as the `leaks` code), I get:

```
$ valgrind --suppressions=suppressions --leak-check=full --num-callers=100 ./leaks
==43063== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==43063== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==43063== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==43063== Command: ./leaks
==43063== 
--43063-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--43063-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97!
--43063-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 2 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 4 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 8 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 16 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN fcntl 97! (repeated 32 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3406, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43063-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 8 times)
--43063-- UNKNOWN host message [id 412, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43063-- UNKNOWN host message [id 222, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x60f]
--43063-- UNKNOWN task message [id 3410, to mach_task_self(), reply 0x60f]
==43063== 
==43063== HEAP SUMMARY:
==43063==     in use at exit: 22,245 bytes in 187 blocks
==43063==   total heap usage: 263 allocs, 76 frees, 28,341 bytes allocated
==43063== 
==43063== LEAK SUMMARY:
==43063==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43063==    indirectly lost: 2,288 bytes in 6 blocks
==43063==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43063==    still reachable: 8,445 bytes in 109 blocks
==43063==         suppressed: 11,512 bytes in 72 blocks
==43063== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==43063== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==43063== 
==43063== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==43063== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 17)
$
```

And you can see that I need to do some work to suppress some of the allocations, but there are no leaks claimed any more.

That's roughly what you need to do too.  You should be able to install the suppressions along with Valgrind so that you don't have to specify `--suppressions=suppressions` each time.

(I had to trim the outputs to fit within the 30,000 character limit on SO.)